# Why id and itemId never match in that react code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is a simple representation of my real problem in a project, it seems i am missing something in react or may be the problem is not related to react, this is my code https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-northcutt-c3fw4?file=/src/App.js

i need to show the item on the list when click on it, and this never happens because that condition never get true and i don't know why?

```
{id === itemId && el}
```

Comment: `typeof id` returns `string`, while `typeof itemId` is an `object`. And the `itemId` is actually `null` :)

Comment: i think the  problem is not in the type, logging the two variable returns totally different ids

Comment: I don't agree: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click the element, you successfully set the `itemId` value to the `id` of the clicked element:

```
const handleItemClick = id => {
    setItemId(id);
};
```

However, upon re-rendering the component you dynamically generate all new `id` values:

```
id={v4()}
```

It's *highly unlikely* (re: impossible) that the newly generated UUID will be the same as the previously generated one.

Don't generate new UUID `id` values on every render.  Either use static values or perhaps just an incrementing value from `.map()`:

```
{arr.map((el, i) => {
    return <Item
        id={i}
        itemId={itemId}
        item={el}
        handleItemClick={handleItemClick} 
     />;
 ))}
```

Comment: in the real problem i can't use the index like this, because the list items created in a nested maps, so i tried to use sum of the index of outer map with index of inner map but this didn't work, so i went for uuidv4 package

Comment: @SaherElgendy: A sum might not work, but what about a concatenated string?  Something like concatenating the outer value, a hyphen, and the inner value.  So the IDs would be something like "1-1, 1-2, 2-1, 2-2, etc."  Either way, you need a predictable value.  Randomly generating a new UUID will never re-generate the same ones.

Comment: I think, that's it, concatenation, thank you, and i got it now why it doesn't work with uuid

Answer (score 2):

**Issue :**

**`id={v4()}` this will create a new uuid on each `render`**, so when you click `handleItemClick` it update `itemId` and which cause `re-render` and all ids got changed due to `id={v4()}` so this will never get true `{id === itemId && item}`

```
{arr.map(el => {
    return <Item
        id={v4()} // <------ Issue is hear
        itemId={itemId}
        item={el}
        handleItemClick={handleItemClick} 
    />;
})}
```

**Solution :**

```
// instead of creating uuid on render you can create and save it as state, so it won't change on each re-render
const [items, setItems] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4].map(() => v4()));

{items.map(id => {
    return (
    <Item
        id={id} // <----- Then use it like this
        itemId={itemId}
        item={id}
        handleItemClick={handleItemClick}
    />
    );
})}
```

**WORKING DEMO** :

[image: Edit #SO-solved-v4()]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming v4 generates a random ID. 
So `id === itemId` will never be true.

And I don't see itemId being initialized anywhere.

It would be great if you can tell me what is that condition for?

Or try `{id === itemId || item}`

Hope this helps
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First you missed the key prop, when using `map()`. It will just throw the warning, not to worry about much :P.

the main problem in your code is, `v4` will generate random keys on each render. so
the `id` will never be the same as `itemId`. try to use some static id. if you can like the `map` comes with `index`. you may use that

```
arr.map((el,index) => {
return <Item
           id={index}
           key={el}
           itemId={itemId}
           item={el}
           handleItemClick={handleItemClick} 
        />;
});
```